# Are questions about ECS a good fit?

Tags: discussion

I'm quite knowledgeable about using Amazon ECS (container hosting solution) and I'd be able to write questions and answers (if required).

What is your opinion on such questions? Would they be a good fit, or would it be too "operations/infra" ?

Comment: Shoot, I was hoping you were talking about the [ECS](http://american-data.com/)  I used to work on...  Would be a bad fit for devops though.

Answer (score 7):

As long the question is clear and helpful for others and it's not too broad, you're welcome to post your own self-answered questions.

See: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/55075)

Answer (score 3):

My main concern would be too generic questions, the goal is *not* to rehash a system documentation.

Now if you have specific (focused) uses cases you struggled with and wish to share them, that's absolutely OK in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about that. We have about a year of experience with ECS so far and we did encounter problems or scenarios not covered by the (too) generic documentation.
I was thinking about actual usage questions like how to manage software versions VS tasks definitions versions (no best practices, afaik) or how to manage environment properties within the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; with the caveat that the asker should keep in mind that they are engaging a community of DevOps experts and *not necessarily* a community of ECS experts.

There may be knowledgeable individuals such as yourself among us, but our entire set won't be comprised of ECS experts. We, overall, will be especially well-versed in DevOps processes relating to ECS, but maybe not-so-much the nitty gritty of how containers work, for example. Even those questions may not be off-topic here -- depending on their specific scope -- but they may receive an answer from a different perspective if asked on SO/SE, or the upcoming cloud proposal.

Technical Stack Exchange sites of this nature often have some overlap with SO/SE especially, and that's okay! Knowing what set of expertise you want to engage when asking a question is part of learning to use this network.